# How can I execute arbitrary code via JSON and how to sanitize the input

Tags: python, json, security, jsonpickle

In the [documentation](https://jsonpickle.github.io/) of Python's jsonpickle module for JSON serialization and deserialization it states that

> Loading a JSON string from an untrusted source represents a potential
>   security vulnerability. jsonpickle makes no attempt to sanitize the
>   input

But I wonder how is it possible for an attacker to execute arbitrary code via JSON messages?

Also, what is the best way to sanitize the input as suggested in the documentation? JSON data in my application is not trust-worthy (it came from the clients that send JSON messages).

Comment: This article may be helpful for you: http://versprite.com/og/into-the-jar-jsonpickle-exploitation/

Answer (score 2):

`jsonpickle` is not JSON. `jsonpickle` allows to create arbitrary Python-Objects that potentially do harmful things. Sanitizing means, that the JSON objects only contain data, that can be interpreted by `jsonpickle`. Normally wrong data would lead to exceptions, but can may be used to trigger unwanted behavior.

The `__reduce__` exploit (see, for example [Into The Jar | Exploitation of jsonpickle](http://versprite.com/og/into-the-jar-jsonpickle-exploitation/))

```
jsonpickle.decode('{"py/object": "list", "py/reduce":[{"py/type": "subprocess.Popen"}, ["ls"], null, null, null]}')
```

is only one direct way to execute any command. More subtle ways depend on your actual code.

So the short answer is, not to use `jsonpickle` in an untrusted environment. Use normal JSON and check the input before using it.

Comment: "jsonpickle allows to create arbitrary Python-Objects that potentially do harmful things" -- how is it possible? Suppose that I use `jsonpickle.decode` to deserialize incoming JSON data. What can an attacker put in this JSON data to execute arbitrary code?